# Learning more about father than just his name

Tags: birth-records, death-records

I have my biological father's name and that is all. He and my mother were never married. He was born somewhere in Colorado around the turn of the 20th century.

My investigation turned up three men with the same name around that time in Colorado.

How can I research that?

The name is all I have, nothing else. My mother is dead; she never spoke to me about him. I think I'm out of luck.

Comment: Have you considered having an autosomal DNA test done?  There are so many people who have been tested at AncestryDNA that there’s a reasonable chance that a child, grandchild, cousin, etc of his may match to you.

Comment: Did the DNA bit, but only got approximate locations. Nothing specific.

Comment: What is the largest number of cM that any of your matches has with you, when that person does not appear to be from your mother’s side?

Comment: Was your father's name on your birth certificate? Usually the fathers age is included which may help you narrow it down a bit.